# Unit Test output in MSBuild/TFS 2008

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

I have a build in TFS 2008 which includes the running of a UnitTest project.

I have configured my build as such that in the drop folder after each build, I get a StyleCop.log, FxCop.log and would like to place the trx or output from the unit tests here also.

I can see that my unit tests are running as part of the build, however currently I cannot find were the output is saved to or find a way of setting the ouput to my drop location ($(DropLocation)\$(BuildNumber)\MyUnitTests.txt)

My unit tests are included by using the following:-

```
<RunTest>true</RunTest>
...
<ItemGroup>
    <TestContainer Include="$(OutDir)\%2aMyUnitTests.dll" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Can somebody help explain how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just realised my unit tests are not running. I do-not have visual studio installed on the build server and as such mstest.exe is missing which runs the tests.

Comment: I've managed to get this working by installing VS2008 pro on the build server and using an exec task to run mstest.exe. Not pretty, but works.